# Accept NaN as result of calculation with undefined

Tags: typescript

I got very attached to JavaScript’s way of handling `undefined` in calculations. For example:

```
function (a) {
    let c = a.b - 1;
    console.log(c || '');
}
```

But I am now working on a TypeScript project with strict mode enabled. So, I tried this:

```
function (a:{b?:number}) {
    let c:number = a.b - 1;
    console.log(c || '');
}
```

The compiler complains that `a.b` is “possibly undefined.” Well, I know that a.b *will* be `undefined` quite often. But I am also sure that I can deal with the resulting `NaN` for `c`.

What’s the most elegant solution here?

Comment: Info: NaN type as a proposal https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty was is to tell the compiler a.b is not defined:

```
let c = a.b! - 1
```

A slightly longer way is to add an undefined check into the calculation:

```
let c = a.b?a.b - 1:undefined
```